# Is it haram to be reusing online coupons over and over by making new accounts?

Tags: makruh

Is it allowed because there is a website that has a promo for every new account gets 5 dollars off so is it allowed to be remaking the account so I can keep getting that 5 dollars off?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the terms & conditions of the site. If the site says it is not allowed, you are breaking a contract which is not allowed according to Sharia (haram). If not, the site may tolerate this (probably, in that case still having a margin) and it's allowed.

The same rules will probably apply according to stately law (which is in general also part of the contract, thus relevant)